# tree.hh - C++ Leaf Traversal

Tags: c++, tree

The output from the following code is incorrect.  It should only output the leaves in the tree:

```
tree<Node> gameTree;
tree<Node>::iterator root = gameTree.insert(gameTree.begin(),Node(14));
tree<Node>::iterator first = gameTree.append_child(root,Node(32.0));
tree<Node>::iterator second = gameTree.append_child(root,Node(64.0));
gameTree.append_child(second,Node(21.0));
gameTree.append_child(second,Node(24.0));

tree<Node>::iterator begin = gameTree.begin_leaf();
tree<Node>::iterator end = gameTree.end_leaf();
int x = 0;
while (begin != end) 
{ 
    cout << begin->value << endl; 
    begin++;
}
```

But it outputs:

```
32
64
21
24
```

when the output SHOULD be:

```
32
21
24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs you should be using a leaf_iterator rather than an iterator, the output you're seeing is from an in order traversal, you want to do a leaf traversal I'm guessing.

btw, thanks for posting this I was just starting in a search for a tree container

hth

Comment: Agh, that was great.  Thanks very much!

FIXED:

tree<Node>::leaf_iterator begin = gameTree.begin_leaf();

etc.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the iterator class is actually just a typedef for the pre_order_traversal class.  So when you set the result of `gameTree.beginLeaf()` (which returns a leaf_iterator) to an iterator, it invokes the copy constructor of pre_order_iterator because there's a constructor defined for `pre_order_traversal(const iterator_base&)` (iterator_base is the superclass for all other iterators, including the leaf_iterator), so this creates a new pre_order_iterator from the leaf_iterator.  Then when you use that iterator, it does a depth-first traversal rather than iterating through the leaves.  If you switch to leaf_iterator instead of iterator, the problem will disappear.

This is also why the direct form mentioned in a comment below (where the value is not assigned to an iterator) works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `tree<>` is, nor do I know the semantics of `append_child`, but from what I see, 32, 64, 21 and 24 are all below the root of the hierarchy (children and grandchildren of 14); I don't see a problem.

Why exactly should 64 be skipped, but not 24?

Comment: It actually goes 14 -> 32,64 -> 21,24.  tree<> is from tree.hh. http://tree.phi-sci.com/documentation.html

Comment: That is not a standard, nor a widely known library. You should have mentioned it in the question. Anyways, I've updated my answer; still don't see a problem. Maybe post a sketch in ascii art about how it is, and how it should be.

Comment: This is not an answer (which I wont downvote, because there is no actual question). Anyway, you have a point that the OP provides insufficient information.

Comment: I apologize.

            14

           /  \

          32  64

             /  \

            21  24


The leaf nodes are the ones which possess no children.  The funny thing is if I use the command:

cout << (gameTree.begin_leaf()+=i)->value << endl;

where 0 < i < 3, it doesn't include 64.  It's only when I use ++ on the iterator...

EDIT: ASCII art failing...